# Highcharts: 3D Columns overlap improperly on the right

Tags: jquery, highcharts, 3d

Here is a [jsfiddle of a 3D Highchart column graph](http://jsfiddle.net/avfdmrL9/1/) pulled directly from Highchart's website.  My only changes were to add another data set, and change `alpha`, `beta`, and `depth`, mainly just to highlight the issue.

Take a look at the columns to the right of the chart.  The right of the two data sets improperly overlaps the left of the two data sets.  It is correct from the center of the graph to the left, but the further you get to the right, the more obvious the issue is.

So my question is - is this a Highcharts bug, or is my code incorrect and there is a better way?

Comment: This issue is already solved on Highcharts GitHub: http://jsfiddle.net/avfdmrL9/2/

Comment: Ah, so the only difference in what you posted is from where Highcharts is being imported - GitHub in this case. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, I think that this issue will be fixed in future Highcharts versions and then it will be possible to have correct zIndexing in columns with your links